# GAM fit on single smooth won't predict above a certain horizontal threshold

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I'm a beginner to fitting GAM's. I'm just using a simple formula to fit a GAM using mgcv in R:

```
model <- gam(y ~ s(x, k=10, bs="gp"), data = df, method = "REML")
```

The issue is, no matter what I put for `k`, the predictions will not extend above a horizontal threshold.

```
preds <- predict(model, newdata = df, type = 'response', se = TRUE)
df_preds <- as.data.frame(preds)
plot(df$y, type='l', lwd=2)
lines(df_preds$fit, lwd=2, col='red')
```

How can I interpret and/or fix this?

[image]

Comment: From the plot, it seems that X and Y are quite independent. If you fit a simple linear regression, I am pretty sure that the parameter will not be significant.

Comment: @Eryna The OP hasn't plotted the response against `x` (they don't pass any `x` in to the `plot()` command. In such circumstances, R uses the row number (it calls it `Index`) in the plot, as the `x` variate *on the plot*. There is nothing in this post that indicates the magnitude of the relationship between the smooth of `x` and the response `y`.

Comment: If you are a beginner in GAMs, why are you trying to use the Gaussian process smooth? There's a reason this smooth is not the default; the Gaussian process only fits into the penalized spline with quadratic penalty framework of models estimable by mgcv if you specify the length scale (beyond which points are effectively up correlated). If you don't specify the length scale (and you didn't specify it) then a simple heuristic is used that is motivated from a spatial setting with two coordinates. The default sets the length scale to the max separation in `x` of any pair of observations. 1/2

Comment: As you haven't told us anything about what your data are, or what the actual setting is, or why you want to fit a Gaussian process, or shown us what the estimated smooth function is, that's is too little to go on here to provide anything concrete. One thing that stands out to me is that all your response values lie between 0 and 1; if so, the model you fitted assumes that the conditional distribution of the data $y_i$ is Gaussian with mean $\mu_i$, and that seems unlikely given the limits on the values taken by $Y$ as shown in your plot. What is `y`? 2/2

Comment: _why are you trying to use the Gaussian process smooth?_
Precisely because I'm a beginner and didn't realize that to be an issue :) Thanks for the pointer there. Yes, my y is a percentage of one thing in a mixture of two things. Trying to predict the percentage based on a few features. I had noticed this artifact on another problem as well where the y was not constrained between 0 and 1 (and I've tried the default smooth which had the same artifact). My question I guess is more general as to what I should do when I see this behavior? Does it just depend on the situation?